# List view option in catalog search page is not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, product-list

By default, My catalog page load on grid view.

I can't switch to list view and Sort by from there. I didn't change any core files, some of the time the layered navigation to doesn't work.

Is there any solution to fix this type of issues in magento 2?

Comment: check your browser console is there any error related to Js ? or something else ?

Comment: no error in console